# How to take value based on curent iteration, (or value passed in fuction), and map it to the row and column (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I've got a data frame with coordinates, like this

```
df <- data.frame(first_x = c(1:5),
                 first_y = c(1:5),
                 second_x = c(1:5)*2,
                 second_y = c(1:5)*2)
```

And I want a **function** to generate something like this.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x= df[1,"first_x"], y= df[1,"first_y"]))+
  geom_point(aes(x= df[1,"second_x"], y= df[1,"second_y"]))
```

I tried to do it with `for` loop whitch at 1st iteration takes columns number *1* and *2*,
at 2nd column *3* and *4*, and so on, but...

```
list_of_geoms <- list()

column <- 1

for (x in 1:(length(df)/2)) {
  
  new_geom <- geom_point(aes(x= df[1,column], y= df[1,column+1]))
  
  list_of_geoms <- append(list_of_geoms, new_geom)
  
  column <- column+2
}
```

this is the resoult.

```
[[1]]
mapping: x = ~df[1, column], y = ~df[1, column + 1] 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity 

[[2]]
mapping: x = ~df[1, column], y = ~df[1, column + 1] 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity
```

so, it takes **the name** of the variable no its **value**.

In the end, I would like to turn it into a function.

```
generate_geoms_list <- function(df, row, column=1) {
  
  list_of_geoms <- list()
  
for (x in 1:(length(df)/2)) {
    
    new_geom <- geom_point(aes(x= df[row, column], y= df[row, column+1]))
    
    list_of_geoms <- append(list_of_geoms, new_geom)
    
    column <- column+2
  }
  
  return(list_of_geoms)
}

list_of_geoms <- generate_geoms_list(df, row=1)
```

***PS. Further explanation.***
*Function below by @Allan Cameron, did what I asked for :)*

I want to generate plot like **[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5P5m.png)**, but I want to be able to change number of variables dynamically. In the beginning, I did it like this.

```
ggplot(df_coords[1,])+
  geom_point(aes(x=0, y=0), color = "red")+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= df_n[1,1], y= df_n[1,2]))+
  geom_text(aes(x= Height_x, y= Height_y, label = "Height"), nudge_y = 0.1)+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= Weight_x, y= Weight_y))+
  geom_text(aes(x= Weight_x, y= Weight_y, label = "Weight"), nudge_y = 0.1)+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= Reach_x, y= Reach_y))+
  geom_text(aes(x= Reach_x, y= Reach_y, label = "Reach"), nudge_y = 0.1)+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= SLpM_x, y= SLpM_y))+
  geom_text(aes(x= SLpM_x, y= SLpM_y, label = "SLpM"), nudge_y = 0.1)+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= Str_Def_x, y= Str_Def_y))+
  geom_text(aes(x= Str_Def_x, y= Str_Def_y, label = "Str_Def"), nudge_y = 0.1)+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= TD_Avg_x, y= TD_Avg_y))+
  geom_text(aes(x= TD_Avg_x, y= TD_Avg_y, label = "TD_Avg"), nudge_y = 0.05)+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= TD_Acc_x, y= TD_Acc_y))+
  geom_text(aes(x= TD_Acc_x, y= TD_Acc_y, label = "TD_Acc"), nudge_y = 0.1)+
  
  geom_point(aes(x= Sub_Avg_x, y= Sub_Avg_y))+
  geom_text(aes(x= Sub_Avg_x, y= Sub_Avg_y, label = "Sub_Avg"), nudge_y = 0.1)+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= Height_x, xend= Weight_x, y= Height_y, yend= Weight_y))+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= Weight_x, xend= Reach_x, y= Weight_y, yend= Reach_y))+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= Reach_x, xend= SLpM_x, y= Reach_y, yend= SLpM_y))+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= SLpM_x, xend= Str_Def_x, y= SLpM_y, yend= Str_Def_y))+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= Str_Def_x, xend= TD_Avg_x, y= Str_Def_y, yend= TD_Avg_y))+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= TD_Avg_x, xend= TD_Acc_x, y= TD_Avg_y, yend= TD_Acc_y))+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= TD_Acc_x, xend= Sub_Avg_x, y= TD_Acc_y, yend= Sub_Avg_y))+
  
  geom_segment(aes(x= Sub_Avg_x, xend= Height_x, y= Sub_Avg_y, yend= Height_y))
```

First I **normalized** values in columns, then **change them to coordinates** evenly placed in the circle with this function. (*propably, there is a better way to do this*)

```
df_to_coordinates <- function(df) {
  
  base_angle <- 360/length(df)
  
  column_names <- names(df)
  
  x_cords_df <- map2_dfc(.x= df, .y=seq_along(column_names),
                         ~ round(.x * cos_my(base_angle *.y ), 2))
  
  nm_cos <- str_c(names(x_cords_df), "_x")
  colnames(x_cords_df) <- nm_cos
  
  x_cords_df$id <- replicate(nrow(x_cords_df),seq(1:nrow(x_cords_df)))
  
  y_cords_df <- map2_dfc(.x= df, .y=seq_along(column_names),
                         ~ round(.x * sin_my(base_angle *.y ), 2))
  
  
  nm_sin <- str_c(names(y_cords_df), "_y")
  colnames(y_cords_df) <- nm_sin
  
  y_cords_df$id <- replicate(nrow(y_cords_df),seq(1:nrow(y_cords_df)))
  y_cords_df
  
  x_y_cords_df <- inner_join(x_cords_df,y_cords_df, by="id")
  
  x_y_cords_df <- subset(x_y_cords_df, select = -c(id))
  
  x_y_cords_df <- subset(x_y_cords_df, select = sort(colnames(x_y_cords_df)))
  
  return(x_y_cords_df)
```

Here is the sample of dataframes

```
df_coord <- structure(list(Height_x = c(0.46, 0.34), Height_y = c(0.46, 0.34), 
               Weight_x = c(0, 0), Weight_y = c(1, 0.37), 
               Reach_x = c(-0.49, -0.35), 
               Reach_y = c(0.49, 0.35), SLpM_x = c(-0.12, -0.19), 
               SLpM_y = c(0, 0), Str_Def_x = c(-0.48, -0.46), 
               Str_Def_y = c(-0.48, -0.46), 
               TD_Avg_x = c(0, 0), 
               TD_Avg_y = c(-0.07, -0.02), 
               TD_Acc_x = c(0.17, 0.35), 
               TD_Acc_y = c(-0.17, -0.35), 
               Sub_Avg_x = c(0.01, 0), 
               Sub_Avg_y = c(0, 0)), 
               row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Although it's possible to do something like this, I really suspect that there is a better way to achieve your end goal. Are you able to explain _why_ you need the function so that we can think about better approaches?

Comment: @Allan Cameron, I'll try to post explanation here later today, or tomorrow morning :)

Comment: Did my answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aes_string` on the `names` of the passed data frame:

```r
generate_geoms_list <- function(df, row, column = 1) {
  
  result <- list()
  nm     <- names(df)
  while(column < length(df)) {
    result <- c(result, 
                geom_point(data = df[row,],
                           aes_string(x = nm[column], y = nm[column + 1])))
    column <- column + 2
  }
  result
}

list_of_geoms <- generate_geoms_list(df, row=1)

list_of_geoms
#> [[1]]
#> mapping: x = ~first_x, y = ~first_y 
#> geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity 
#>
#> [[2]]
#> mapping: x = ~second_x, y = ~second_y 
#> geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity
```

To use these geoms you would need to do something like this:

```r
p <- ggplot(data = df)
p$layers <- list_of_geoms
p
```

[image]